# How to get the value on the textbox in server vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have created a textBox in the server side(vb.net) like this:

```
Dim r As New TableRow
Dim c As New TableCell
Dim txt As New TextBox

For i = 1 To 10
    c = New TableCell
    txt = New TextBox
    txt.ID = "recev" & i
    txt.ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Static
Next
```

This create me all the textBox in my page.
Now the user need to enter numbers in the textBox and press on OK button.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the numbers.

If I do in the html `<form>` so I can do this:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    txt = "recev" & i & ""
    Request.Form(txt)   
Next
```

and it's work. But I can't use `<form>` because of other reasons.

Can I use something else to get the data the user insert?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you could use Javascript, in this way:

Event 'click' of your button: `javascript:process_stuff();`

Your javascript, would be **something like** this:

```
function process_stuff(){
  var your_values = [];
  for (var indice = 1; indice <= 10 ; indice++) {
    if ($("#recev" + indice).length){
      your_values[indice ] = $("#recev" + indice).val();
  }
  PageMethods.PM_receipt_info(your_values);
}
```

Server side:

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub PM_receipt_info(aValues)

for each sValue as String in aValues   debug.print(sValue ) next
```

Where aValues is an array with the textboxes values'.

Another try: if you need a postback, can do it JS __doPostBack ('',params), passing that values sepparated with character , etc.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for something in the server side only,
like Request.Form(txt), without js.
Can I do it with findControl maybe?

Comment: No. I think I don't understand you. 
¿How do you want to use Request.Form without a Form? ¿Or asp textboxes without a form? 
I think that I you want to do a POST, you will need a Form. One o your alternatives it's Javascript with a PageMethod, as I said.